# How does the Symbol of Gajz interact with healing powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, implements

Our cleric just picked up the Symbol of Gajz([ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6376)) as a reward in our current quest It contains the following property:

> Property: When you use a healing power
>   through this holy symbol, choose acid,
>   cold, fire, lightning, or poison. Each
>   ally affected by the power gains
>   resist 5 to the chosen damage type
>   until the end of your next turn. If
>   the ally is a dragonborn, the
>   resistance increases by 5. If the ally
>   wears or wields one or more items from
>   this set, the resistance increases by
>   5.

Does this work with *Healing Word*? None of his healing powers have the "Implement" keyword. It seems that the property of this symbol is useless, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Well, there is one that is Implement and Healing, which is `Beacon of Hope`, but I can't think of any others offhand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extrapolating from [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75842/19686342/Rules_Q38;A_FAQ__ask_a_simple_question&post_num=3620):

> Healing Strike wouldn't be affect by this  because it doesn't have the healing and implement keywords; healing strike is a weapon keyword power.  But, yes.  In order for this implement to come into play, the power being used has to be used through the implement, so it has to have the implement and healing keyword.

This implement is liked because of its set bonus, mainly. [Astral Seal](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=8286) does technically benefit from the property, though they have to hit the enemy to benefit. There are a number of dailies and encounters that explicitly benefit though, [Beacon of Hope](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=913), [Mantle of Glory](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1407). However, I would say that other classes could benefit more from the symbol.

[Spirit's Shield](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=5389) has excellent synergy, [Stirring Shout](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=4989) is unbelievably good, as it lasts the entire encounter and grants an effect to allies every time they hit the targeted enemy, and so on.

Basically it's one of the many items that, if built around, can be excellent. If just dropped randomly, it's a curiosity and nothing more.

Comment: +3/4 and rounding up. I don't agree with the Healer's Implement feat. While the flavour is correct, 4e is a very Keyword/Rulesey game, and since it doesn't actually add the Implement keyword, I don't think it would apply. GM could certainly allow it if they were feeling benevolent though.

Comment: @Cthos, agree that it's a function of DM's interpretation. But it did need to be mentioned.

Comment: And that I don't disagree with.

Comment: @Cthos - interesting point on the feat not adding the implement keyword. This item definitely seems to be of limited use for our cleric. However, it was dropped with Rovikar's weapon, so it will be of use that way.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton - Healer's Implement does not say it adds the Impelement keyword, so it does not. Saying otherwise is not interpretation, but houseruling. These are different things.